# Un programa de registro con estructuras que a la hora de la union me marca error

Tags: array, c, string, lista, estructuras

Estoy haciendo un programa con estructuras. El cual registra empleados por nombre, apellido materno, paterno, codigoID y contraseña. Todo esto en un menú. El problema es que cuando declaro este menú como una función por si sola sin el demás contenido del programa funciona perfectamente, pero a la hora de unirla al programa entero meda el error de (subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector).

También intenté usare el código de esta función como tal en el programa (sin declarar como función), dándome el mismo resultado. Depués al hacer la unión coloque el puntero a mi índice ahora dándome este error (request for member ******** in something not a structure or union).

Tambien intente usar ->, pero o no supe como declararlo, o creo que solo sirve con enteros. No se que mas pueda ser, aquí el código:

```
struct menu
{
  char IDempleado[50], nombre[51],origiN[50],apellidop[50],origiP[50],apellidom[50],origiM[50],contrasena[51];
}x[MAX];

void menuG(int argc, char *argv[])

{

   system("COLOR F0"); //FUNCION PARA CAMBIO DE COLOR

   int menu1,x;


   char *gerent="gerente",*contraG="1212",usuario[20];

   int        

   submenu,capturado=0,*indice=0,i,encontrado,n=0,datmodifica,modifica;

    char contra[20],buscar[20],retry='r';
    char num[50]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50'};
    while (retry=='r'||'R')
    {
    do
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t***BIENVENIDO GERENTE***\n");
        printf("\n\n\t-Menu para gerente. Aqui se puede dar de alta a los empleados-\n\n");
        printf("\t1.Nuevo  \n\n\t2.Mostrar todos \n\n\t3.Buscar por codigo (IDempleado) \n\n\t4.Bucar por apellido paterno(Clientes y/o socios) \n\n\t5.Modificar \n\n\t6.Eliminar \n\n\t7.Reportes \n\n\t8.Cambiar de usuario\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&submenu);
        switch(submenu)
        {
            case 1:if (capturado==MAX)
                        {
                            printf("\nYa se lleno la base de datos\n");

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            *contra=0;
                            n++;
                            printf("\n\n\t\t    **HA SELECCIONADO, NUEVO EMPLEADO**\n\n");
                            getch();
                            printf("\nIntroduzca nombre del empleado: ",i+1);
                            scanf ("%s",x[indice].nombre);
                            printf("\nIntroduzca 1er apellido: ");
                            scanf ("%s",x[indice].apellidop);
                            printf("\nIntroduzca 2do apellido: ");
                            scanf ("%s",x[indice].apellidom);
                            printf("\n\nAhora digite el codigo ID (Preferencia numeros): ");
                            scanf ("%s",x[indice].IDempleado);

                            strcpy(x[indice].origiN,x[indice].nombre); //
                            strcpy(x[indice].origiP,x[indice].apellidop);  //creamos las variables origi para guarfar los nombres y apellidos originales copiandolos en el mismo lugar con strcpy
                            strcpy(x[indice].origiM,x[indice].apellidom); //

                            strncat(contra,x[indice].nombre,1); //
                            strncat(contra,x[indice].apellidop,1);    //aqui tomamos el perimer caracter de cada nombre y apellido y le adjutamos un numero aleatorio
                            strncat(contra,x[indice].apellidom,1);
                            strncat(contra,num,n); //

                            strcpy(x[indice].contrasena,contra); //aqui copiamos de la cadena contra a la varibale de contrasena para ir guardando las mismas

                            printf("\n\nSu contraseña es: %s",x[indice].contrasena); //aqui se muentra la contraseña generada
                            printf("\nSu IDempleado es: %s",x[indice].IDempleado); //el ID puesto con anterioridad

                            indice++;
                            capturado++;
                        }
```

El error me lo a partir de aquí, en el scanf de nombre.

```
    printf("\nIntroduzca nombre del empleado: ",i+1);
                            scanf ("%s",x[indice].nombre);
                            printf("\nIntroduzca 1er apellido: ");
                            scanf ("%s",x[indice].apellidop);
                            printf("\nIntroduzca 2do apellido: ");
                            scanf ("%s",x[indice].apellidom);
                            printf("\n\nAhora digite el codigo ID (Preferencia numeros): ");
                            scanf ("%s",x[indice].IDempleado);
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agredecería he estado atorado algunos días en esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los errores son claros y concisos, tal vez no los entiendes por estar en inglés; te los traduzco:

> > subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
>
> > el valor indexado no es ni una formación ni un puntero ni vector

> > request for member ******** in something not a structure or union
>
> > se solicita el miembro ******** sobre algo que no es una estructura o unión

El primer error hace referencia a que no se puede usar el operador de indexado (los corchetes `[]`) sobre algo que no puede ser indexado, las únicas estructuras de datos que pueden ser indexadas son las formaciones, los punteros y los vectores.

El segundo error hace referencia a que no se puede pedir acceder a los miembros de una estructura de datos que no tiene miembros internos, las únicas estructuras de datos que pueden tener miembros internos son las estructuras y las uniones.

---

Examinando tu código vemos que estás indexando el objeto `x` y estás pidiendo acceder a miembros internos del resultado de ese indexado:

```
scanf ("%s",x[indice].nombre);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Indexado por 'indice' y miembro 'nombre'.
scanf ("%s",x[indice].apellidop);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Indexado por 'indice' y miembro 'apellidop'.
scanf ("%s",x[indice].apellidom);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Indexado por 'indice' y miembro 'apellidom'.
scanf ("%s",x[indice].IDempleado);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Indexado por 'indice' y miembro 'IDempleado'.
```

Pero el objeto `x` no es ni una formación, ni un  puntero ni un vector ni una estructura ni una unión, es un entero (`int`):

```
int menu1,x;
//        ^ <--- 'x' es de tipo 'int'.
```

"***Casualmente***" existe otro objeto con el mismo nombre que es una formación de estructuras, pero habita en un ámbito superior:

```
  struct menu
  {
    char IDempleado[50], nombre[51],origiN[50],apellidop[50],origiP[50],apellidom[50],origiM[50],contrasena[51];
  }x[MAX];
// ^ <--- 'x' es una formación de estructuras 'menu' con 'MAX' elementos.
```

En muchos lenguajes de programación, se permite repetir el nombre de identificadores en diferentes ámbitos, pero siempre tendrá preferencia el ámbito más local, esto se conoce como ensombrecimiento de variables ([*variable shadowing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)). En tu caso la variable `x` del ámbito de `main` ha ensombrecido la variable homónima del ámbito global; si eliminas la variable `x` del ámbito de `main` (a la que parece que no le das ningún uso) tu problema puede que se solucione.

Comment: Gracias amigo mi problema fue resuelto. Tal como dijiste la x innesesario se superponia a la de la formación de la estructura, lo cual causaba el error. Una la vez la removi todo funciono con normalidad. Esta pregunta ya fue resuelta. Por si alguien le sirve.

Comment: @diegoguillen me alegra saber que esta respuesta te sirvió. Por favor, márcala como aceptada para que la publicación quede completa. Saludos.